# How to call a fortran subroutine with allocatable type output from c sharp

Tags: c#, fortran90

I have tried to do this for hours. I have the Fortran code, and want to use it in my c sharp project.

```
  subroutine lean(nx,nlam,flmin,
  ulam,thr,isd,intr,maxit,lmu,a0,ca,ia,nin,rsq,alm,nlp,jerr)
  real x(no,ni),y(no),w(no),vp(ni),ca(nx,nlam),cl(2,ni)                 
  real ulam(nlam),a0(nlam),rsq(nlam),alm(nlam)                          
  integer jd(*),ia(nx),nin(nlam)                                        
  real, dimension (:), allocatable :: vq;  
  ...
```

I used the following code in my c sharp to import this subroutine.

```
    [DllImport("lean.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void lean_(
        ref int nx, 
        ref int nlam,
        ref float flmin,
        ref float[] ulam,
        ref float thr, 
        ref int isd,
        ref int intr, 
        ref int maxit, 
        ref int lmu,
        [In,Out]  ref float[] a0,
        [In,Out]  ref float[,] ca,
        [In,Out]  ref int[] ia,
        [In,Out]  ref int[] nin,
        [In,Out]  ref float[] rsq,
        [In,Out]  ref float[] alm, 
        ref int nlp, 
        ref int jerr);
```

And I got this error

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

In this function, there are two parameter I don't know how to handle, jd is of type jd(*) 
and vp which is allocatable. The rest should be ok. Anyone knows how to handle these parameter types? Thanks.

Comment: Neither `jd` nor `vq` is listed as arguments in the Fortran.  In the case of `jd` that's an error - assumed size arrays must be dummy arguments.  c# would not be able to work with an allocatable dummy argument (if you had one - at the moment you don't) without lots of Fortran compiler specific games.

Answer (score 1):

The calling convention should be either StdCall or ThisCall.  Cdecl means the caller is responsible for stacking and unstacking the parameters.  StdCall means that the caller is is responsible for stacking but the callee is responsible for unstacking.  ThisCall does a time saving thing by putting the first parameter into ECX and pushing the rest of the stack.  Cdecl is only used by C/C++ and any programming language that uses the varargs concept.  The rest of the world uses StdCall.  Not sure what uses ThisCall.

You'll probably need to put an unsafe {} around the whole call.

jd and vq are allocated internally by Fortran so you don't need to worry about them.  Presumably they are deallocated before exit.  Fortran has its own heap.

If it is multithreaded, you need to declare the arrays as fixed.  They can't be moving about when Fortran is processing them.